# Trouble with calling API in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, urlsession

Please check if there's something wrong 
I have a block of code that use API to get a list of film but nothing happens.

```
    typealias JSONDictHandler = (([String : Any]?) -> Void)
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://dev.bsp.vn:8081/training-movie/movie/list")!)

    let token = "dCuW7UQMbdvpcBDfzolAOSGFIcAec11a"
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "app_token")

    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        // if nothing wrong
        if error == nil {
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                switch httpResponse.statusCode {
                case 200: // successful case
                    if let data = data {
                        do {
                            let jsonDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)

                            print(jsonDict)

                        } catch let error as NSError {
                            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    }

                default:
                    print("HTTP Response Code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                }
            }

            // there's something wrong
        } else {
            print("Error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
```

Besides, there're some parameters I have to insert to the url, how can I do this?

Comment: What error you are facing ?

Comment: What is your output?

Comment: Use pod moya...

Comment: @TaimoorSuleman I tried giving a breakpoint inside dataTask but there's nothing happened

Comment: I tried putting it on Postman and "Could not get any response" :)). So, maybe there's something wrong with the url and relating things

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is helpful!!
Allow arbitrary load to yes

[image]

Comment: it doesn't work but, I tried putting it on Postman and "Could not get any response" :)). So, maybe there's something wrong with the url and relating things.

Comment: Oops, my bad, the URL is wrong. Now, it works. Thanks!

Comment: Always Welcome!!